# How to setup a terminal prefix

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, prompt

I'm running kali linux and until I was using the root account, everything was fine, but then I made a personal account (name: koumakpet) and used that terminal instead of

```
koumakpet@kali: ~$
```

there was only

```
$
```

[image]
As you can see in the image, I was trying to change my prefix by PS1='prefix' but that didn't went quite as expected, it seems like it can't detect the variables such as '\u' in string and neither it can detect the colors.

I have also noticed that pressing up arrow (to see the last thing I typed) will not actually show you the last command, but instead, it just write `^[[A` (same with down arrow: `^[[B`)

How am I supposed to set the terminal prefix to what should be default `koumakpet@kali: ~$` and enable the colors

Comment: That `PS1` syntax is for the `bash` shell. Presumably, that new user has been assigned a different login shell (run `ps` to see what shell is running in that terminal), use `chsh` to change the login shell to `/bin/bash` (and logout+login again), or adapt that `PS1` syntax to that of user's login shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas 
`chsh` command fixed it it was using `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`
but why did it set sh as the default instead of bash?

Comment: I suppose that's the default shell used by whatever application you used to create that account. `/bin/sh` is the only shell you're sure to find on any Unix-like system, so that's a sensible default.

Comment: Ok, thank you than, you can write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `PS1` syntax is specific to the `bash` shell.

Presumably, that new user has been assigned a different login shell.

Use `chsh` to change the login shell to `/bin/bash` (and logout+login again), or adapt that `PS1` syntax to that of user's login shell.

`ps` shows the shell in question is `sh`. I suppose that's the default shell used by whatever application you used to create that account. `/bin/sh` is the only shell you're sure to find on any Unix-like system, so that's a sensible default.